# Passing a javascript-php associative array to weekly calendar array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, associative-array

I am facing a problem while using the Weekly event calender[Weekly event calender](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html)

In this  demo there is static array passed for events the code for that is :

```
 function getEventData() {
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  var month = new Date().getMonth();
  var day = new Date().getDate();

  return {
     events : [
        {
           "id":1,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),
           "title":"Lunch with Mike"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 14),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45),
           "title":"Dev Meeting"
        },
        {
           "id":3,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17, 45),
           "title":"Hair cut"
        },
        {
           "id":4,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day - 1, 8),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day - 1, 9, 30),
           "title":"Team breakfast"
        },


     ]
  };
```

}

I want this data come from mysql using PHP. for this I write  the php code

```
 $query="Select id, start_time, end_time, title from calendar_events where status=1";

 $result=mysql_query($query);

 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
  $i=1;
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $myarray[] = array("id"=>$i,"start"=>$row['start_time'], "end"=>$row['end_time'], "title"=>$row['title']);
  $i++;
}
```

I am getting the this array in Javascript as:

```
<script>
    var myarr = <?php  echo json_encode($myarray); ?>;
</script>
```

Now I want this data in the calendar. I tried many ways but couldn't get success.
Please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, try this :

```
<script>
    function getEventData() {
     return json_encode('events'=>$myarray);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacko07... I tried this but its showing me syntax error

Comment: Sorry. You should do this way :
 json_encode(array(array('events'=>$myarray)))